# Why name node and data node implemented as daemon threads?

Tags: hadoop

Why name node and data node implemented as daemon threads instead of normal threads in Hadoop?

Comment: A daemon thread is just a special type of normal thread...

Answer (score 0):

Daemons are meant for long running processes, such as namenode or datanode